# making svg wave entire screen size and stick to bottom

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following svg

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
<path fill="#e7008a" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L40,133.3C80,139,160,149,240,128C320,107,400,53,480,69.3C560,85,640,171,720,170.7C800,171,880,85,960,42.7C1040,0,1120,0,1200,32C1280,64,1360,128,1400,160L1440,192L1440,320L1400,320C1360,320,1280,320,1200,320C1120,320,1040,320,960,320C880,320,800,320,720,320C640,320,560,320,480,320C400,320,320,320,240,320C160,320,80,320,40,320L0,320Z"></path>
</svg>
```

But when I add it to my html document, it doesn't fill the entire width of the screen and there is a space between it and the bottom. It's parent is a footer tag.

How can I make it full width and stick to bottom

Comment: you could try adding preserveAspectRatio="none' to the svg element.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you have shown which tries to get it to go to the bottom - and the bottom of what, the viewport or the footer or… Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
svg {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**This might help you if you want to stick it in the bottom of the screen**

Comment: question ask abt how to fill full width which has not been addressed

Comment: just add width: 100%

Answer (score 0):

you can do sth like this. add a div as a container and use the svg as a background of this division which fills the whole page:

```
<div className={classes.container}>
//
</div>
```

```
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100vh',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundImage: 'url(./PictureAddress.svg)',
  
  },
```